# jTweetsAnywhere not working on live server, only on local server

Tags: javascript, jquery

jTweetsAnywhere works on my local server, but isn't displaying tweets on the live server.  Just an empty box and I even included the anywhere.js and consumer key.

In my head:

```
    <script src="http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=YQDAme3v6zI0CR1FiWCg&v=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jTweetsAnywhere/jquery.jtweetsanywhere-1.3.1.min.j"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jTweetsAnywhere/jquery.jtweetsanywhere-de-1.3.1.min.j"></script>
```

Then the element to target:

```
        <div id="twitterbox" class="sidebar-header">
        <h2><a href="http://twitter.com/overbitespics">Follow OverbitesPics on Twitter</a></h2>
        <div id="tweetFeed" class="clear">
    </div>
```

Must be missing a step or something goes wrong when making a call from the host server?

Answer (score 0):

In your first code block you include "jtweetsanywhere-1.3.1.min.j". The correct filename ends on **.js**.

Also missing is the call to jTweetsAnywhere somewhere in your body after the DOM is loaded.

Can't imagine that this code is running on a local server.